# Can I delete multiple file extensions at same time in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

Is there way to add multiple extensions (e.g. pattern = ('*.txt' or '*.doc')

```
import os, fnmatch
def find_files(directory, pattern):

    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):

        for basename in files:
            if fnmatch.fnmatch(basename, pattern):
                filename = os.path.join(root, basename)

                yield filename

def find_files_to_list(directory, pattern):

wanted_files = find_files_to_list('/original_project/', '*.html')

for filename in find_files('/copy_project/', '*'):

    if filename not in wanted_files:
        os.remove(filename)

    file_list = []
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
        for basename in files:
            if fnmatch.fnmatch(basename, pattern):
                filename = os.path.join(root, basename)
                file_list.append(filename)

    return file_list

wanted_files = find_files_to_list('/original_project/', '*.html')

for filename in find_files('/copy_project/', '*'):

    if filename not in wanted_files:
        os.remove(filename)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you just want a basic string operation, no?

```
if filename.endswith(('.txt','.doc')):
    os.remove(filename)
```

Or, negating it,

```
if not filename.endswith('.html'):
    os.remove(filename)
```

`.endswith` accepts a tuple of things you want to match against, returning `True` if any match, so if you wanted to keep .html and .txt extensions:

```
if not filename.endswith(('.html','.txt')):
    os.remove(filename)
```

Comment: In above program I am keeping files with extension '*.html' but I can't add say '*.txt' to same program. The logic is to keep files you need and delete rest.

Comment: I can't because I have directory with bunch of files and folders. So if I use os.listdir it won't delete the files in subfolder. And if I use os.walk I can't copy them back in same format. So I thought it's easy to keep what i need and delete rest but I runs into above problem.

Comment: I'm still not getting it.  Try editing what you're trying to do into your OP and why your current solution doesn't work.

Comment: SO in my current solution here I run into problem:          wanted_files = find_files_to_list('/original_project/', '*.html')      
I also want to keep '*.txt' along with '*.html' but I don't know how to add it to above.

Comment: Okay, so just.. add it into the .endswith tuple like I showed in my first example.